# How bind data to the angular material table

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am getting below response from api

```
[
 {
  "name": {
    "grade": A,
    "commission": 271.07
  },
  "name": {
    grade": B,
    "commission": 160.37
  },
  
 }
]
```

I have tried to bind this data to material table. But I am unable to bind this data. Can anyone help me to bind this data to the table

Comment: Would be great if you can share your minimal attempt, so we can know what is your issue/where are you stuck and provide a solid solution. Thanks.

Comment: your json structure of data is incorrect. name property is duplicate. it must be unique

Comment: Yeah..It's working..Thank you @GRD

Comment: @GRD can you put this in answer so Sneha can mark as accepted. That would helps others also to find the solution.